# Increase margin for TextView compound drawable

Tags: android, layout

I have the following code

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_search_background"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/info"
    android:text="@string/msg_decode_notice"/>
```

It looks like this:

[image: Notice]

The problem is that the margin from the edge of the field to the icon differs from the margin from the icon to the text. How can I increase the indentation on the right without resorting to the ImageView + TextView? I try to make my layout as flat as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `android:drawablePadding` attribute to specify the padding between the drawable (the icon) and the text. You can also use the `android:paddingStart` and `android:paddingEnd` attributes to specify the padding of the text field.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_search_background"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/info"
    android:drawablePadding="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="24dp"
    android:text="@string/msg_decode_notice"/>
```